# Composition of a fuzzy set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I'm trying to learn about Fuzzy alone. I'm having difficulties with understanding intuitively the composition of a fuzzy set. According to the definition in the book:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdOUR.png)

*Composition of a fuzzy set A ⊆ X and a fuzzy relation R ⊆ X × Y shall be notated A ◦ R and defined as a fuzzy set B ⊆ Y, then

B = A ◦ R*

As far as I understood that if we assume that we have 2 sets in universes X and Y. And we find the relation of these sets. Then we take another set A from universe X. If we calculate the composition of this with that relation that we calculated before we get set B which is related to set A.

Comment: What does the T above * and the ensuring | mean?

Comment: It's the operation of t-norm on arguments and | was my mouse's pointer